# (SKNode) not convertible to string (it was working with old xCode)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, nsarray, updates

In my apps I was using this piece of code and it worked perfectly:

```
var data3: NSArray = [] //1
for gg  in data3{ //2
    var hh:String = gg["percentage"] as String //3
    perchomerec = hh.toInt()! //4
}
```

Now I updated my `xCode` and `OSx` version and now this same piece of code gives this error (on line //3):

> [SKNode] is not convertible to String

What do I have to change?

Comment: println() `gg` to see what `gg["percentage"]` is, is it a String? Oh, nicely named variables, so descriptive...not.

Comment: Where is SKNode comming from when data3 is an NSArray? That would make gg an AnyObject.

Comment: Hmm you are going somewhere.. gg isn't defined, has that something to do with it?

Comment: What is inside data3?

Comment: Try to remove "as String" and see what error you get in xcode, because xcode is not very used to swift yet in telling what is actually causing the error.

Comment: @Arbitur
println(data3) gives (
        {
        percentage = 33;
    }
)

Comment: @Arbitur When I remove the "as String", the error moves one line down it gives: [SKNode] does not have a member named .toInt()

Comment: Yes there certainly is a Dictionary in there but you have to cast gg into a Dictionary.

Comment: Thank you, how Do I do that?

Comment: @Arbitur I tried for gg:NSDictionary in data3{, but that gives also error..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`data3` seem to be of type `[[String:Int]]` based on your responses on my comments.

So by changing NSArray to [[String:Int]] or just simply removing NSArray completely and letting Swift determine the type by itself.

I guess your question is in pseudo-code so my guess is how you set that data3's data:

```
let data3 = [["percentage" : 33]] // Swift will determine this type to: [[String:Int]]

for gg in data3 { // gg will become [String:Int]
    perchomerec = gg
}
```

Or if you still want the NSArray type then to cast gg in a for loop you have to cast the array itself:

```
for gg in data3 as! [[String:Int]]
```

## Edit

If the array changes then it has to be an `NSArray` or `[AnyObject]` and then you have to test to cast for every possible type.

```
for gg in data3 {
    if let dict = gg as? NSDictionary {
        if let str = dict["percentage"] as? String, nr = str.toInt() {
            perchomerec = nr
        }
        else if let nr = dict["percentage"] as? Int {
            perchomerec = nr
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I can not do that because data3 comes from a php file on the internet. So it changes from time to time. How can I do this without using the let data3 = [["percentage" : 33]]?

Comment: Thank you, no more errors in compiling, but when running, it gives (lldb) on that line

Comment: Forgot you had an NSDictionary inside that arr x) I updated my answer again.

Comment: Casting can be confusing in the beginning with Swift ;) Because its so type safe.

Comment: One more quick question:  var recimages = [NSString()] //line 1 recimages += [str]//line 2, also doesn't work anymore.. how come?

Comment: Swap () from [NSString()] to [NSString]()

Comment: Thanks, Do you have skype or something where I can find you for small questions?

Comment: No sorry. Just make another question on SO and I might find it or someone else ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since Swift 1.2 `as` operator can only be used for upcasting. When downcasting, you should use `as!` or `as?` (detailed description can be found e.g. in [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TypeCasting.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH22-ID341)).

```
var hh:String = gg["percentage"] as! String
```

Comment: Thank you, but than I get: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value. println(gg) gives: {
    percentage = 33;
}

Comment: Well, if you are not 100% sure that `gg["percentage"]` is a `String`, than use `as?` and handle `nil` values as needed..

Comment: I tried: var hh:String? = gg["percentage"] as? String //This gives (lldb) error with that line highlighted

Comment: "Handle nil values as needed" .. I suggest you read a bit about how to properly deal with optionals

Comment: btw there is a warning: Cast from [SKNode] to unrelated type String always fails, what do they mean?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to use `!` or `?`, although from Jakub Vano's answer it sounds like using optional unwrapping would be more suitable for your code. If you don't expect `hh` to not be a `String` or not be `nil` then I also suggest you check your code elsewhere.

```
var data3: NSArray = []
for gg  in data3 {
  if let h = hh as? String {
    perchomerec = h.toInt()!
  }
}
```

Comment: apparently gg is a "anyobject", How Do I make a NSString of it?